# How can I draw cylinder inside a sphere like this picture with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I am trying to draw a cylinder inside a sphere like this picture
[image]

I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\def\r{{2*sqrt(3)}}
\def\d{-60}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords]
\path
coordinate (O) at (0,0,0)
coordinate (I) at  (0,0,2)
coordinate (A') at  (0,\r,4)
coordinate (A) at  (0,\r,0);
\coordinate (B) at ($(O) + (\d:{2*sqrt(3)} and \r)$);
\coordinate (B') at ($(B)+(0,0,4)$);
\coordinate (O') at ($(O)+(0,0,4)$);
\draw[dashed] (A)--(A') (B) --(B') (O)--(O') (O)--(A) (I) --(A);
\foreach \v/\position in {I/left,O/below,O'/above,A/below,B/below,A'/left,B'/left} {
    \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
}
\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{4}%
%\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{{2*sqrt(3)}}%
\fill[ball color=orange!70, opacity=1.0] (I) circle (\R);
\end{scope}
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size = 0.3](I,O,A);
\draw [thick] (B) arc (\d:90:\r);
\draw [thick, dashed] (A) arc (90:310:\r);
\draw [thick] (B') arc (\d:90:\r);
\draw [thick, dashed] (A') arc (90:310:\r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got
[image]

The cylinder look very bad. How can I repair it?

Comment: What is bad with your solution? For me its quite the same. What is missing?

Comment: Note that A and B are not the edges of the cylinder (x=\pm \r).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't understand you Comment. Please help me.

Comment: It turns out that A and B were NOT in the right place, albeit only about 2 degrees off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Points (A) (B) (A') and (B') are not the edges of the cylinder, but rather the points where the visible edge of the sphere (circle) and the visible edge of of the cylinder (ellipse) intersect, which depend on the viewing angles.
Points (C) and (D) represent the visible right and left edges.

[image: math]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\def\myangle{70}%
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\myangle}{0}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{2*sqrt(3)}% sphere radius=4, cylendar height=4
\path% common coordinates
  (0,0,-2) coordinate (O)
  (0,0,0) coordinate (I)
  (0,0,2) coordinate (O')
  (O) ++(0:\r) coordinate (C)% right edge
  (O) ++(180:\r) coordinate (D);% left edge
\draw[dashed,thick] (C)-- ++(0,0,4) (D)-- ++(0,0,4);
\draw[dashed] (O)--(O');
\begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
      \fill[ball color=orange!70, opacity=1.0] (I) circle (4);
\end{scope}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\mynumer}{2*cos(\myangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mydenom}{\r*sin(\myangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\quadrant}{ifthenelse(abs(\mynumer)<abs(\mydenom), 0,
  ifthenelse(\mynumer>0, 1, 2))}% 0=side, 1=top, 2=bottom

\ifcase\quadrant
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\intercept}{asin(\mynumer/\mydenom)}
  \path
    (O) ++(-\intercept:\r) coordinate (A)
    (O) ++(-180+\intercept:\r) coordinate (B)
    (O') ++(\intercept:\r) coordinate (A')
    (O') ++(180-\intercept:\r) coordinate (B');
  \draw [thick] (B) arc (-180+\intercept:-\intercept:\r);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (A) arc (-\intercept:180+\intercept:\r);
  \draw [thick] (B') arc (-180-\intercept:\intercept:\r);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (A') arc (\intercept:180-\intercept:\r);

  \foreach \v/\position in {I/left,O/below,O'/above,A/below,B/below,A'/left,B'/left} {
    \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
  }
\or% top
  \path
    (C) coordinate (A)
    (D) coordinate (B)
    (A) ++(0,0,4) coordinate (A')
    (B) ++((0,0,4) coordinate (B');
  \draw [thick] (O') circle (\r);
  \draw [thick, dashed] (O) circle (\r);

  \foreach \v/\position in {I/left,O/below,O'/above,A/below,B/below,A'/left,B'/left} {
    \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
  }
\or% bottom
  \path
    (C) coordinate (A)
    (D) coordinate (B)
    (A) ++(0,0,4) coordinate (A')
    (B) ++((0,0,4) coordinate (B');
  \draw [thick,dashed] (O') circle (\r);
  \draw [thick] (O) circle (\r);

  \foreach \v/\position in {I/left,O/below,O'/above,A/below,B/below,A'/left,B'/left} {
    \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
  }
\fi

\draw[dashed] (O)--(A) (I) --(A);
\tkzMarkRightAngle[size = 0.3](I,O,A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Is there a code true for every cylinder?

Comment: Yes and no.  You need one solution for small \phi and another for large \phi.  Then you need to calculate \theta using pgfmath (I just used a calculator).

Comment: I shall  try to write a general code. When I see difficult, I need your help. Can you help me?

Comment: The tricky bit is the test for `h \cot\phi/r_x`.  pgfmath has a ifthenelse command, but it basically only affects \pgfmathresult.  LaTeX has `\ifdim\len<1pt\relax ... \else ... \fi` construction but you will need to append `pt` to the number.

Comment: New thought: use \pgfmathparse or \pgfmathsetmacro to assign 0,1,2 and possibly 3 then use \ifcases\pgfmathresult\relax ... \else ... \else ... \fi to implement the images.  BTW, \relax means "Stop looking for more digits.  This number is done."

Comment: I am sory. I am too busy now. I have not enought time to try.

Comment: The revised solution can handle can handle any angle.  Except \tkzMarkRightAngle cannot handle 0 degrees (divide by zero).

Comment: I tried to change your code with some replaces as 
`\def\R{4}%
\def\h{4}%
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\myangle}{0}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,tdplot_main_coords]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{sqrt(\R^2-\h^2/4)}% sphere radius=4, cylendar height=4
\path% common coordinates
  (0,0,-\R/2) coordinate (O)
  (0,0,0) coordinate (I)
  (0,0,\R/2) coordinate (O')
  (O) ++(0:\r) coordinate (C)% right edge
  (O) ++(180:\r) coordinate (D);% left edge
\draw[dashed,thick] (C)-- ++(0,0,\h) (D)-- ++(0,0,\h);`
It works. Can you write a general code when I chooce every `R` and `h`?

Comment: BTW, \R*\R is MUCH faster than \R^2 = exp(2*log(\R))

Comment: @ John Kormylo, When I change \def\myangle{50}, It seems wrong.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Note that 0 is the north pole and 90 is the equator.