# Cylinder inside the Sphere

Tags: plot, tikz-3dplot

In the post, [How can I draw cylinder inside a sphere like this picture with Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400808/how-can-i-draw-cylinder-inside-a-sphere-like-this-picture-with-tikz/669438#669438),
the cylinder is sketched inside the sphere , but I want it to be slightly different.
I don't want A, B, A', B', ..., to appear in it.
I want it to be like this picture Is it possible to share the design code of this photo?
with respect
[image]

Comment: I don't want A, B, A', B', ..., to appear in it

Comment: Remove this lines `\foreach \v/\position in  {I/left,O/below,O'/above,A/below,B/below,A'/left,B'/left} {
    \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
  }'

Comment: Thanks a lot, Done.