Is there a good illustration to accompany a short article about LaTeX?
I'm doing a short recommendation for a Swedish teacher magazine, about letting the pupils learn LaTeX. I'd need some kind of illustration for this. Perhaps a rather complicated formula, some colour coded LaTeX code? It should first and foremost look good, but also preferably be correct...
All help is appreciated! Any sugestions will be taken as examples, nothing will be used as it is without the illustrators permission. Note that the magazine does not pay for supplied material.

something like page 14 from here https://pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/1615-Mittelbach.pdf?

While I occasionally include PDF tutorials (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400808/how-can-i-draw-cylinder-inside-a-sphere-like-this-picture-with-tikz/401048?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C33.4414#401048 for example), I don't save the source.

If it's for pupils, you should include examples with TikZducks and TikZlings! See Extravaganza2024 (source: https://github.com/TikZlings/Extravaganza2024)
